# How to determine the order of a reaction from given concentrations?

Tags: kinetics

> In the presence of an acid, the initial concentration of cane sugar was reduced from 0.20 to 0.10 molar in 5 hours and from 0.2 to 0.05 molar in 10 hours.
>
> What is the order of the reaction?

My attempt

So i found the first 2 rate

R1 = 0.015
R2 = 0.010

And i tried comparing this with the final concentrations of the 2 processes

I am getting the answer as 3

How do i solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by determining the half life of the reaction, so from the first one we have 5 hours to half the concentration, and from the second data we get the same half life.
So in conclusion, the rate order is 1 because the half life is constant

Comment: I have a question   What if the concentration is not half after a period of time what do i do ?